# How to cut image as icon in Blender?

Tags: python, interface

I want to import an image into blender and quote some parts according to row and cols as icon displayed in template_icon_view(). BUT template_icon_view() could only import icon from file path. Is there any alternative way? When it is done, it should be like fig3.Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "quote" in this context.

Comment: If I get some pixels using bpy.data.images['1.png'].pixels[], could I generate an icon with these pixels?

Answer (score 2):

Although I have solved this problem for a long time, I see better answers in other places, so I sent them out
The first is the imbuf library, but the documents are not very detailed and haven't been updated for a long time
https://developer.blender.org/T54272
And then this
[How to merge external images together in script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166285/)
Then my method is that the PIL library cuts the pictures, saves them to Blender's cache directory, and loads them through this path

````
from . PIL_library64 import Image
import sys

def cut_image(image,x,y):
    # x指横上切的刀数
    width, height = image.size
    item_width = int(width / x)
    item_height = int(width / y)
    box_list = []
    # (left, upper, right, lower)
    for i in range(0,y):
        for j in range(0,x):
            box = (j*item_width,i*item_height,(j+1)*item_width,(i+1)*item_height)
            box_list.append(box)
    image_list = [image.crop(box) for box in box_list]
    return image_list

# 保存
def save_images(image_list):
    from os.path import exists
    from os import makedirs
    import bpy
    temppath=bpy.app.tempdir
    print(temppath)
    if not exists(temppath+"mi2bl"): # 判断文件夹存在
        makedirs(temppath+"mi2bl") # 创建文件夹
    index = 1
    file_list=[]
    for image in image_list:
        image.save(temppath+"mi2bl\\"+str(index) + '.png', 'PNG')
        file_list.append(temppath+"mi2bl\\"+str(index) + '.png')
        index += 1
    return file_list

#主函数-分割图片，存储到blender的项目缓存文件夹中
def image_crop(file_path, x, y):
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    #image.show()
    image_list = cut_image(image,x,y)
    file_list=save_images(image_list)
    return file_list
```
````